# MySQL select data on the basis of source type

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I am working on `MySQL`. I have a table in which there are some records. Below is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `mdc_meters_data` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`msn` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  
`kwh_t` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`data_date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`s_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52702 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 /*Data for the table `mdc_meters_data` */

 insert  into `mdc_meters_data`(`id`,`msn`,`kwh_t`,`data_date_time`,`s_type`) values(49641,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:02:17','WAPDA'),
(49642,'00209701','1476.59','2020-11-01 00:02:47','Sync Meter'),(49643,'00209702','1389.79','2020-11-01 00:03:17','Sync Meter'),(49644,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:04:57','WAPDA'),(49645,'00209701','1476.6','2020-11-01 00:05:28','Sync Meter'),(49646,'00209702','1389.81','2020-11-01 00:05:58','Sync Meter'),(49647,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:07:38','WAPDA'),(49648,'00209701','1476.6','2020-11-01 00:08:08','Sync Meter'),(49649,'00209702','1389.81','2020-11-01 00:08:38','Sync Meter'),(49650,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:10:19','WAPDA'),(49651,'00209701','1476.6','2020-11-01 00:10:49','Sync Meter'),(49652,'00209702','1389.82','2020-11-01 00:11:19','Sync Meter'),(49653,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:12:59','Generator'),(49654,'00209701','1476.61','2020-11-01 00:13:30','Sync Meter'),(49655,'00209702','1389.83','2020-11-01 00:14:00','Sync Meter'),(49656,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:15:40','Generator'),(49657,'00209701','1476.61','2020-11-01 00:16:10','Sync Meter'),(49658,'00209702','1389.84','2020-11-01 00:16:40','Sync Meter'),(49659,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:18:20','Generator'),(49660,'00209701','1476.61','2020-11-01 00:18:51','Sync Meter'),(49661,'00209702','1389.84','2020-11-01 00:19:21','Sync Meter'),(49662,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:21:01','Generator'),(49663,'00209701','1476.61','2020-11-01 00:21:31','Sync Meter'),(49664,'00209702','1389.85','2020-11-01 00:22:01','Sync Meter'),(49665,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:23:42','WAPDA'),(49666,'00209701','1476.62','2020-11-01 00:24:12','Sync Meter'),(49667,'00209702','1389.86','2020-11-01 00:24:42','Sync Meter'),(49668,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:26:22','WAPDA'),(49669,'00209701','1476.63','2020-11-01 00:26:53','Sync Meter'),(49670,'00209702','1389.88','2020-11-01 00:27:23','Sync Meter'),(49671,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:29:03','WAPDA'),(49672,'00209701','1476.63','2020-11-01 00:29:33','Sync Meter'),(49673,'00209702','1389.88','2020-11-01 00:30:03','Sync Meter'),(49674,'4A60193390662','2068.3','2020-11-01 00:31:44','WAPDA');
```

Same is in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a2da6/1)

**What I have done**

I am able to carry out the start and end date time of a source named `WAPDA` and in that time I have carried of the `MAX` value of `kwh_t`. I want to check it for every hour in 24 hours span. So I have managed the query like that way.

```
SELECT 
msn, 
MAX(kwh_t), 
MIN(data_date_time), 
MAX(data_date_time) 
FROM mdc_meters_data
WHERE s_type = 'WAPDA' 
AND data_date_time >= DATE '2020-11-01' 
AND data_date_time < DATE '2020-11-02'
GROUP BY msn, DATE(data_date_time), HOUR(data_date_time)
ORDER BY msn, DATE(data_date_time), HOUR(data_date_time);
```

The above query gives me

```
msn          | MAX(kwh_t)| MIN(data_date_time)   | MAX(data_date_time) 
=======================================================================
4A60193390662| 2068.3    | 2020-11-01T00:02:17Z  | 2020-11-01T00:31:44Z
```

**What I want?**

The above result is not correct as seen in [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a2da6/1) at `2020-11-01T00:02:17Z` the `s_type` is `WAPDA` and at `2020-11-01T00:12:59Z` the `s_type` is `Generator`. Then again at `2020-11-01T00:23:42Z` the `s_type` is again `WAPDA` and so on. I want to set my query in a way that it will give proper information according to the `s_type` like below

For **WAPDA**

```
 msn         | MAX(kwh_t)| MIN(data_date_time)   | MAX(data_date_time) 
=======================================================================
4A60193390662| 2068.3    |  2020-11-01T00:02:17Z | 2020-11-01T00:10:19Z
4A60193390662| 2068.3    |  2020-11-01T00:23:42Z | 2020-11-01T00:31:44Z
```

For **Generator**

```
msn          | MAX(kwh_t)| MIN(data_date_time)   | MAX(data_date_time) 
=======================================================================
4A60193390663| 1000.3    |  2020-11-01T00:12:59Z | 2020-11-01T00:21:01Z
```

As there is no record for the `s_type = WAPDA` after `2020-11-01T00:10:19Z` and before `2020-11-01T00:22:01Z` so the query must start from the value of that particular `s_type` from where it records began. Same is applied for `s_type=Generator`

How to achieve it?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem. To solve your problem, you need to also group your readings according to the `s_type` value, so that (in your sample data) you extract two distinct groups of `WAPDA` values (separated by the `Generator` values). Basically you need to keep an overall row number as well as a row number for each island (so counting restarts whenever `s_type` changes). Subtracting the latter from the former gives you a constant number for each island, on which you can then group.

This is a tricky problem to solve in MySQL 5.x because of the lack of the `ROW_NUMBER` function, however that functionality can be emulated using variables. This query should give the results you want:

```
SELECT msn,
       s_type,
       MAX(kwh_t) AS max_kwh, 
       MIN(data_date_time) AS min_date_time, 
       MAX(data_date_time) AS max_date_time
FROM (
  SELECT md.*,
         @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
         @rst := CASE
             WHEN @st  = s_type THEN @rst + 1
             WHEN @st := s_type THEN 1
             ELSE 1
         END AS rst
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM mdc_meters_data
    WHERE s_type != 'Sync Meter'
      AND data_date_time >= '2020-11-01' 
      AND data_date_time < '2020-11-02'
    ORDER BY data_date_time
  ) md
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @rst := 0, @st := '') init
) m
WHERE s_type = 'WAPDA'
GROUP BY msn, rn - rst, DATE(data_date_time), HOUR(data_date_time)
ORDER BY msn, min_date_time
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
msn             s_type  max_kwh     min_date_time           max_date_time
4A60193390662   WAPDA   2068.3      2020-11-01 00:02:17     2020-11-01 00:10:19
4A60193390662   WAPDA   2068.3      2020-11-01 00:23:42     2020-11-01 00:31:44
```

Demo (also showing results for `s_type = 'Generator'`) [on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=29417dff2872391fe0d493dd57e116d7).

Comment: yes it did work. I was out of town so didn't check it. There is one more change I want to do but i'll be posting another question someday. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @FaisalQayyum good to hear. It had been a while so I wanted to check in and make sure it was useful. I'll look out for your next question - hopefully I can help out again.